# Is it possible, without knowing Python, to animate between orthographic and perspective camera view?

Tags: animation, camera

I want to animate between perspective and orthographic camera views. How can this be done?

I found where people talk about successfully animating between orthographic and perspective camera views in Unity with code, so fundamentally this must be possible. But I don't know Python, so I wouldn't be able to figure it out manually with code in Blender.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9187/599

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To achieve a smooth transition from a Perspective camera to Ortho (and back), @someonewithpc's answer gets you part of the way there. However, that solution just jumps between Perspective and Ortho; the transition is not smooth. Use the following steps:

1. Set a keyframe for your camera's location (<kbd>I</kbd> -> Location)
2. In Camera Properties, set a keyframe for your camera object's Focal Length (it's in the Lens panel) by either <kbd>RMB</kbd> the value and choosing Insert Keyframe or hovering your mouse over the value and pressing <kbd>I</kbd>. (*Note: this assumes that your camera is in Perspective view to start.*)
3. Move forward in time to where you intend to have your transition to Ortho complete.
4. Increase the Focal Length to a very high value (The soft limit is 5000mm, but you can manually enter higher numbers. Typically, however, around 1000mm should be sufficient.) You should notice right now that everything feels zoomed in *very* close. Don't worry about that just yet.
5. Insert a keyframe for your new Focal Length (hover -> <kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>RMB</kbd> -> Insert Keyframe).
6. Grab (translate/move) your camera along its local Z-axis... you will need to move it very far. Try moving it by 100 units to start (<kbd>G</kbd> -> <kbd>Z</kbd> -> <kbd>100</kbd> -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>). You will also probably need to adjust your camera's clip range... both the Start value (to remove artifacts) and the End Value (to ensure visibility). Keep grabbing your camera and moving it along it's local Z-axis until it looks very similar to the Orthographic camera (you can quickly switch between Perspective and Ortho in the Lens panel of Camera Properties to check).
7. When you're happy that your perspective view closely matches the ortho view, insert a keyframe for your camera's location (<kbd>I</kbd> -> Location).
8. Make sure your camera is set to Perspective view in the Lens panel of Camera Properties and insert a keyframe on the Perspective/Ortho/Panoramic buttons as described in @someonewithpc's answer (hover over buttons and press <kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>RMB</kbd> -> Insert Keyframe).
9. Step forward *one* frame <kbd>right arrow</kbd>.
10. Change the camera view mode from Perspective to Ortho from the Lens panel of Camera Properties.
11. Insert a keyframe for the camera's viewmode as described in #8 and @someonwithpc's post.

That should do it. This should get you a smooth transition from Perspective to Ortho. I know it looks like a lot of steps, but I was just overly thorough with my description. It's pretty easy to do.

Comment: Hitchcock would be proud of this solution ;-)

Answer (score 5):

It is possible!

First you need to select your Camera, then go to the *Properties* panel, and under the *Camera* tab, *Lens* subsection, you can choose your lens type;

[image]

However, a perhaps little know feature, is you can animate almost everything, so just press <kbd>I</kbd> or right click it (<kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd>) and select *Insert Keyframe*. Make sure the lens type you want to transit from is selected, that the current frame is one before when you want your transition to happen.

[image: Animate]

Then just select the other one move to the next frame and repeat the process for the *Orthographic* lens.

Comment: Small note, you can also hover and press I.

Comment: @gandalf3 Indeed, but I seem to have forgotten...

Comment: However, this will *not* be a smooth transition; it's a hard jump. To do a more smooth transition from perspective to ortho, you're going to need to animate the focal length of the perspective camera. A very high focal length (maximum, I think is 5000mm in Blender) is roughly the same as orthographic. And in order to get that working, you'll also need to animate the local z-location of the camera as you increase the focal length. Once you're at "near-ortho equivalent" in perspective view, *then* you can keyframe from Perspective to Ortho to get a smooth transition

Comment: @Fweeb True; add that as another answer.

Comment: @fweeb I just noticed this. The answer should include this info, because without this it isn't really an animation, is it?

Comment: @jt0dd, true, though upon re-reading the question, it specifically asks about how to do this in Python rather than the interface.

Comment: @Fweeb no it doesn't... re-read it, please. It says _without_ knowing Python.

Comment: @Fweeb I don't think there is a maximum focal length, 5000 is just a soft limit. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2832/599

Comment: @Fweeb getting this right will be great, but I'm trying now and your recipe isn't quite working yet, because animating to focal length 5000 zooms me in like 100 times further than the orthographic view shows the scene. I could perhaps play with that number for hours, but it would be great to know how to get it right every time.

Comment: Edit to my previous comment: I didn't follow all of the steps shown in his comment, it does work ^_^ It should be posted as the answer

Comment: My apologies for misreading. I've created an example .blend file. I'll upload it and post an answer.