# How to change camera from perspective to orthographic?

Tags: camera

I can't find any property that does this.

I'd also like to change from one to the other with an animation setting halfway through my video, but not sure how I'd do that either.

---

Update: the animation question is answered here: [Is it possible, without knowing Python, to animate between orthographic and perspective camera view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17997/is-it-possible-without-knowing-python-to-animate-between-orthographic-and-pers?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: you can switch from a camera to another but it's another question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Lens*, press the *Orthographic* button, and choose the *Focal Length* to zoom in/zoom out.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I was looking on the Object tab, didn't see Camera. Thanks.