# How to switch to orthographic in blender 2.8?

Tags: camera, orthographic

I saw this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119743/how-to-change-camera-from-perspective-to-orthographic), but in 2.8 the camera settings just looks like this:
[image]

How do I switch the camera to be in orthographic mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've pretty much confirmed this was a bug in the beta version that I had downloaded. I downloaded a newer beta (build date is February 17th, 2019) and opened up my project and when I went to the lens settings, I was able to see all of the settings and set the camera to orthographic mode.

Answer (score 5):

It's not available in EEVEE. You have to switch to cycles render for ortho camera.

Comment: For me it seems to be the other way around. In EEVEE mode I have a full set of camera settings, whereas in Cycles I see a panel like the screenshot in the question, with only a Depth of Field section.

Comment: Ah yeah, same for me. If I switch to eevee, then I can see all the settings for the lens, but not with cycles (I was using cycles when I asked the question above).