# Is it possible to move vertex along the blender focal length

Tags: vertex-groups

If i arrange vertices in a shape in front view and as I pull those vertices backward from the right view, the shape of the front view changes, it contracts as the vertices are pulled backward. So is their any feature to move vertex along the focal length so that the shape of the front view remains the same.

Comment: I want to model in perspective view using a perspective image    as a loose reference

Comment: Friend I need this feature because while modeling from my imagination, I arrange those vertices according to how it should look in the front view but as I move them back to manage the side view it shrinks in the front view. So is their any feature to enlarge a shape according to focal length as it moves back. By posting this question you should assume I know everything about focal length.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9187/599